# Duplicate methods in Java

Tags: java, methods

My question is probably quite basic but something I've never had to do before, so I'm assuming it's possible in Java (I'm sure it is and I just don't know how). Essentially I have 3 objects which I want to manipulate (3 `BufferedImage`s). For example I want to be able to change the brightness and contrast, which I can do. By doing this I've had to create a separate method for each image where the code is exactly the same. For example:

```
public void increaseBrightnessGreen() {
    RescaleOp rescaleOp = new RescaleOp(1.0f, 10, null);
    rescaleOp.filter(greenImage, greenImage);
    updateGreen();
}
```

Which is then repeated for red and blue but then also duplicated 3 more times to decrease the brightness which is quite a lot of code which is doing very similar stuff. Of course, this applies quite frequently and the brightness example is just 1 of many, the methods to import the images are the same except for changing a few variables and contrast is similar to the above too. I don't know if it matters but all of my code is in one individual class.

As I say, I'm sure there's a way to reduce all this excess duplication of code, I just don't know how.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code improvement rather than code fixing. Please refer to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) where this is ontopic.


Comment: Are you talking about passing in parameters to the method? So you'd call `increaseBrightness(image)` and that function would do the R, G, and B channels?  Then you could surely remove the `increaseBrightnessGreen`, `increaseBrightnessRed`, `increaseBrightnessBlue` methods and combine them into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the method take in the parameter that it should modify. It could also take in the `RescaleOp` so you don't need to create it 3 times (and allow for different `RescaleOp`s.

```
public void increaseBrightness( BufferedImage image )
{
     RescaleOp rescaleOp = new RescaleOp( 1.0f, 10, null );
     rescaleOp.filter( image, image );
     // Don't know what updateGreen does but you could probably do something similar there
     updateImage( image );
}
```

Then you call the method with the image you want to `increaseBrightness` on.

```
increaseBrightness( greenImage );
increaseBrightness( redImage );
increaseBrightness( blueImage );
```

---

```
public void increaseBrightness( BufferedImage image, RescaleOp rescaleOp )
{
     rescaleOp.filter( image, image );
     // Don't know what updateGreen does but you could probably do something similar there
     updateImage( image );
}
```

and call after you create the `RescaleOp`

```
RescaleOp rescaleOp = new RescaleOp( 1.0f, 10, null );
increaseBrightness( greenImage, rescaleOp );
increaseBrightness( redImage, rescaleOp );
increaseBrightness( blueImage, rescaleOp );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course there is a way to not duplicate methods and make a more versatile one! But you have to repeat enough code in this example too..

first of all make 3 statics in your class:

```
static int GREEN = 1;
static int RED = 2;
static int BLUE = 3;
```

then make your ONE method for ALL

```
public void adjustBrightness(int color, boolean increase) {


    if (increase){
         if (color == BLUE){

        //code for blue increment

        }
         if (color == GREEN){

        //code for green increment

        }
         if (color == RED){

        //code for red increment

        }
    else{    //decrease brightness


         if (color == BLUE){

        //code for blue 

        }
         if (color == GREEN){

        //code for green 

        }
         if (color == RED){

        //code for red 

        }


    }
 }
```

you can call this method pretty nicely with 
    adjustBrightness(BLUE, true);

or if you want it more like native speech make 2 more statics:

```
static boolean INCREASE = true;
static boolean DECREASE = false;
```

so now you can have:

```
adjustBrightness(BLUE, INCREASE);
```

and be the same with the last one;

Comment: Don't use statics like that when there are `enum`s for this purpose. They add the benefit of type safety, and if you really insist on using statics, at least make them `final`.

Comment: I surely agree, you are completely right. They have to be final...